# Colocar ícone na lista usando CSS

Tags: jquery, css

Fiz esse script em jQuery para colocar um ícone diferente dependendo da extensão que termina o `href`, mas queria saber como que eu posso colocar o ícone usando o CSS invés da tag `<img>`, pois parece que assim fica meio gambiarra.

```
        <script src="jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $( function(e) {
           $("li a[href $= '.zip']").before("<img src='imagens/icon_zip.gif'>");
           $("li a[href $= '.pdf']").before("<img src='imagens/icon_pdf.gif'>");
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Por CSS não teria como inserir um elemento `<img>` na página, mas você pode usar a propriedade `background-image` para inserir o ícone como imagem de fundo no link.

Basta saber as dimensões do ícone e ajustar um `padding-left` com a largura do ícone mais um pequeno espaço até o texto.

Por exemplo, supondo que seu ícone tenha 24x24 pixels, o `padding-left` poderia ser 24+5 = `29px` (`5px` pixels de espaçamento). Poderia fazer desta forma:

```css
ul{
   list-style: none;
   padding: 0;
}

li a{
   display: inline-block;
   height: 24px;
   line-height: 24px;
   padding-left: 29px;
   margin: 10px;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

li a[href $= '.zip']{
   background-image: url(http://www.iades.com.br/inscricao/Images/icon.zip.gif);
}

li a[href $= '.pdf']{
   background-image: url(https://brava.com.gr/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/pdf-24x24.png);
}
```

```html
<ul>
   <li>
      <a href=".zip">link 1</a>
   </li>
   <li>
      <a href=".pdf">link 2</a>
   </li>
</ul>
```